# Docker env_file not working when running build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

    website:
        build:
            context: website
        env_file: website/config/production.env
```

The `website` service corresponds to this `website/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN apt-get update

COPY src /usr/website
WORKDIR /usr/website

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN python manage.py migrate
```

I also have `website/config/production.env`, with several settings, such as the following:

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=

DJANGO_DATABASE_NAME=
DJANGO_DATABASE_USER=
DJANGO_DATABASE_PASSWORD=
DJANGO_DATABASE_HOST=
DJANGO_DATABASE_PORT=3306
```

If I run `docker-compose config`, the variables show properly under the `environment` key, but when I run `docker-compose build` I get

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: DJANGO_SECRET_KEY is not
>   in your environment

That's because I have this on my `settings.py` file:

```
def require_environ(key):
    if key in os.environ:
        return os.environ.get(key)
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('%s is not in your environment' % (key,))
```

So, the code is working as it should, but the variable is not defined. Why not?

Comment: You can't run database migrations from a Dockerfile at all.  One part of that is that many of the Compose-related settings, including environment variables and networking, aren't available during the build phase.

Comment: Got it. I know what to do then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @David Maze said in the comments above, you can't run migrations from a docker file. The env vars are not available during the build stage, and thus the migrations must/should be run after.

To solve this, I created a script `start.sh`, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Django: migrate
#
# Django will see that the tables for the initial migrations already exist
# and mark them as applied without running them. (Django won’t check that the
# table schema match your models, just that the right table names exist).
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial

# Django: collectstatic
#
# This will upload the files to s3 because of django-storages-redux
# and the setting:
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

#####
# Start uWSGI
#####
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/django-uwsgi.ini
```

The script is ran as the last line of the `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD [ "/usr/start.sh" ]
```